# Fish ID? Small, yellow-finned, tropical fish in Thailand

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, marine-biology

I have not had any luck finding the yellow fish shown in the photo in any of my fish books. I saw them in many places, so they are fairly common. This observation was at around 15 meter depth.

I hope someone here knows it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little Google search I found similar fishes. Says it is golden or yellow damselfish or possibly lemon damsel but I'm not sure because there are some different names for this picture or different pictures for searching same name can be found on Google.

Also, I found a [fish identification page](http://www.fishbase.se/identification/specieslist.php?famcode=350&areacode=&spines=&fins=) on which this fish can be found.

Is this your fish?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think you found it. A Damselfish was also my first guess, but I thought I had ruled them out because none of the books or sites that I looked through had damselfish with fins like this.
Here is a link to the specific Fishbase entry: http://www.fishbase.se/summary/Amblyglyphidodon-aureus.html